# How setup Cycles Compute Device in console

Tags: cycles-render-engine, customization

I am using blender 2.79, and I am trying to set up Cycles Compute Devices devices in system tab of user preferences menu in python console. What I can do is a list of available devices.

```
import _cycles
_cycles.available_devices()
```

and it shows an available device, but I can't find a way to set up this device in user preferences.

[image]

The setting I would like to change is marked by the red box.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 2.79 you can use:

```
import bpy

preferences = bpy.context.user_preferences
cycles_preferences = preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences
cuda_devices, opencl_devices = cycles_preferences.get_devices()

cycles_preferences.compute_device_type = "CUDA"

for device in cuda_devices:
    print('Activating {}'.format(device.name))
    device.use = True
```

In Blender 2.80 you can use:

```
import bpy

preferences = bpy.context.preferences
cycles_preferences = preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences
cuda_devices, opencl_devices = cycles_preferences.get_devices()

cycles_preferences.compute_device_type = "CUDA"

for device in cuda_devices:
    print(f'Activating {device.name}')
    device.use = True
```

Be aware that the script doesn't perform error handling for the case that the device isn't CUDA capable. You will get a `TypeError` with an OpenCL device.